# Why does my jQuery templating approach not work in jQuery 1.9.1 anymore?

Tags: javascript, jquery, templating

Please see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VdZJx/2/

```
$(function()
{
    var li = $($("#link-item-template").html()).find("a").attr({
        href: "javascript:;"
    }).html("Toggle");

    $("ul").append(li);
});
```

This is a templating approach I, and as I've seen even some other libs are using to store and generate html templates.

If you take the jQuery version 1.9.1, let this demo run and watch the console it turns out that [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) throws the following error when you try to generate a new jQuery object out of `$().html()`. See:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <li>
>           <input type="checkbox" /> <a></a>
>       </li>

What can I do to get it to work again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are not really getting proper elements, but the contents of a script tag as a string, which happens to be HTML, a lot of whitespace and newlines is added to the HTML string, and you need to trim that to make it work as a valid selector :

```
$($.trim($("#link-item-template").html()))
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/VdZJx/3/)

Comment: Sweet jesus... I tried everything but not this. This is the correct answer and fixes the problem. Thanks!